# Execute anonymous - switch projects

Tags: execute-anonymous

I have two projects on the folders bar: A and B.
When I open 'Execute Anonymous' it is set to project A.
How do I 'Execute Anonymous' for project B?

Comment: Which IDE/Tool you are using?

Comment: I'm using MavensMate

Answer (score 1):

For **Force.com IDE (Eclipse)** you can directly select project on which you'll execute your script

[image]

For **MavensMate** you can open simultaneously only one project so you will execute your script for project which is opened.

Comment: At least for the Force.com IDE, the project must be *open*, as well. Closed projects can't execute anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

*Right click* on the Project folder from which you want to initialize execute anonymous

In context menu click `'Force.com' > Execute anonymous`

This would start for the project on which you *right clicked*.